# How was President Gerald Ford appointed instead of just succeeding his role?

Tags: united-states, president, vice-president, succession, political-transitions

I’ve heard it said that one of the reasons President Gerald Ford was hated, was because he was appointed President, instead of being elected. And it’a also said he was the only president appointed.
How so? If he was appointed, weren’t all of the Vice Presidents who filled the Presidency for an assassinated president also appointed? How is Ford different?

Comment: I've never heard that that was the reason Ford was disliked. He was disliked by some (mostly Democrats) because he pardoned Nixon after Nixon resigned to avoid impeachment.  The pardon meant Nixon would not face criminal trial. He was disliked by others (mostly conservative Republicans) because Ford was a moderate. Ford beat Ronald Reagan in the Republican primary but lost to Jimmy Carter in the general election.

Comment: @DavidHammen https://youtu.be/y4k4WF72dqk?t=27

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Spiro Agnew, who was elected as Nixon's VP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiro_Agnew), resigned. As the result, [Nixon appointed Gerald Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973_United_States_vice_presidential_confirmation) as his new VP as per the [25th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/25th_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution), who then became the President once Nixon himself [resigned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Nixon%27s_resignation_speech) before completing his term. As such, Gerald Ford became the President without running for the office of neither the President nor the Vice President. This was the only case where the *elected* VP didn't fill the role of the President, in all other cases (deaths/assassinations) the VPs were elected.